# How to change the position of an element when I do a click action

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm designing an application that makes it easy to fetch result from wikipedia. Now What I want to do firstly is that when the search value has been entered into the search bar and I click on the search Icon, I want the search bar to move up and create space for the incoming result. Yes I have some codes but it's not working yet. Also The API call to wikipedia seems not to be working as well, I will also need help with that. Below is the Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  let searchValue = document.getElementById("#searchString").value;

  $(".sbutton").on("click", function() {
    // code to push the wrap div element and icon up the container
    $(".wrap").animate({
      marginTop: "5px"
    });

    let baseUrl = " https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php? ";
    let tailUrl =
      "action=opensearch&format=jsonfm&search=" + searchValue + "&limit=10";
    let wikiLink = baseUrl + tailUrl;

    $.ajax({
      url: wikiLink,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function getWikiData(data) {
        let dDiv = document.createElement("div");
        dDiv = "content";
        dDiv.className = "secondDiv";
document.getElementByClassName("container").append(dDiv);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.opensearch.search.length; i++) {
          $("#content").appendChild(
            "<p>" + data.opensearch.search[2].title + "</p>"
          );
        }
      },

      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to add some css to the element.

```
$(".wrap").css( "marginTop", "5px" );
```

read more about the jQuery css here http://api.jquery.com/css/

Make sure that youcalls the jQuery aswell, easiest way is through cdn, here you go:
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/

here you have working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/6txwmh8L/

Comment: sure you have your jQuery-source before the script-call?

Comment: instead of : ---"    $(".sbutton").on("click", function() {*your code*};   "--- try ---- $('.sbutton').click(function(){ *your code* });

Comment: I isolated the '.wrap' from the other ajax code yesterday and it worked. Also I changed the 'let searchValue = document.getElementById("#searchString").value;' to let searchValue = document.getElementById("searchstring").value; and that was when it worked. However I think I have a COR issue with my wikipedia API

Comment: you´re of course right about the # in the getElementById.. in plain Javascript theres no need på the # because you already declared that there is an id youre looking for. the # is only needed when you using jQuery (in this case). Thats the thing the # does, declaring that you looking for an id, with a dot(.) you looking for a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".wrap").animate({ marginTop: "+=30px"}, 500 );
```

will be more smooth

Comment: both suggestions are not working. I don't seem to know what the issue is.

Comment: your .wrap classed object seems have an absolute position then ?

Comment: I isolated the '.wrap' from the other ajax code yesterday and it worked. Also I changed the 'let searchValue = document.getElementById("#searchString").value;' to let searchValue = document.getElementById("searchstring").value; and that was when it worked. However I think I have a COR issue with my wikipedia API.